# how does one install "audioanalyse0.1.1" module in blender?

Tags: python, game-engine

hello im doing a little project I try to analyse sound from a mic. in the bge. I whant to use numpy pyaudio and audioanalyse. the first two are pretty simple. I have some difficulties trieing to install audio analyse. Does someone kniw how to install it and what version of python to use?

cheers, tim

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask about this. Anyway, a link to this "audioanalyse" module would be great, at least for us to understand what exactly it is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean [Audio Analysis v1.1.0](http://davidjarvis.ca/blender/tools/audio-analysis.shtml) this script was developed for Blender 2.43 (around 2007) and is unlikely to work with the latest releases.

Meanwhile there was an addon [Import_Movement_From_Audio_File](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Import_Movement_From_Audio_File) which could be a better starting point. Unfortunatly it seems that it has been removed from the current distribution (the documentation refers to 2.64.9).

You could get an older Blender version from [here](http://download.blender.org/release/).